# Mark local maximum and calculate gradient in PGFplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I'm using data from a tensometer to generate a stress-strain curve, but I want to find the yield point and the gradient between the start of testing and that point to calculate Young's modulus. Can PGFplots find those points and calculate this? Reading through the manuals suggests this is possible with the `fpu` and mathematics parsing libraries, but I'm currently stuck.

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

%% Main Font list
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Adventor}[Scale=MatchUppercase]
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\usepgflibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepgflibrary{fpu}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotsset{
  compat=newest,
  every tick label/.append style={font=\footnotesize},
  every axis/.append style={font=\footnotesize},
}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma, trim cells=true]{G21-28-tensile-data.csv}\tensiledata

  \def\initialDiameter{5.61}
  \def\initialLength{25}
  \pgfmathparse{(pi * (\initialDiameter) ^ 2)/4}
  \let\initialArea=\pgfmathresult

  \pgfplotstablecreatecol[
  create col/expr={\thisrow{Load} / \initialArea * 1000}
  ]
  {StressCalc}\tensiledata

  \pgfplotstablecreatecol[
  create col/expr={\thisrow{Extension} / \initialLength}
  ]
  {StrainCalc}\tensiledata

  \begin{axis}[
    xlabel={Strain (ε) (\si{\mm\per\mm})},
    ylabel={Stress (σ) (\si{\mega\pascal})},
    xmin=0,
    ymin=0,
    width=20cm,
    height=10cm,
    xtick pos=left,
    ytick pos=left,
    ]
    \addplot[no marks, red] table [x=StrainCalc, y=StressCalc]{\tensiledata} ;
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Stress-Strain graph]

The yield point is the local maximum on the left hand side where the graph spikes (roughly at (0.002,330)), and if I could figure out how to store that point as a coordinate, I could use the `atan` function to find the gradient between that point and (0,0).

The data used to render the graph is here: https://gist.github.com/zoqaeski/8e3f31866f41d3dcfe61c226f6c4a991